# Can I use Spring Data saveAll() method and Hibernate 5 batch?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data

I have a Spring boot application with `application.yml`:

```
spring:
    datasource:
        driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
        url: *my_url*
        password: *my_pass*
        username: *my_username*
    jpa:
        properties:
            hibernate:
                jdbc:
                    batch_size: 15
                    #order_inserts: true
                    #order_updates: true
                    #batch_versioned_data: true
```

When I try to save 200 000 entities using the method `saveAll(Iterable<S> entities)`, it saves all 200 000 entities at the same time, but I want to save batches of 15 entities at a time.

Is it possible to use Spring Data's `SimpleJpaRepository` and Hibernate's batch?

Comment: https://frightanic.com/software-development/jpa-batch-inserts/

Comment: Which version of Spring data are you using?

Comment: @Cepr0, isn't that link a bit old?

Comment: @11thdimension I think no ) https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=batch+insert+in+spring+data+jpa

Comment: @Cepr0 It's from 5 years ago, guy is using Session to do manage  transactions. It's old.

Comment: @11thdimension https://vladmihalcea.com/2017/04/25/the-best-way-to-do-batch-processing-with-jpa-and-hibernate/ 2017-04-25 - the same approach.

Comment: @11thdimension you are not attentive, see last paragraph: **JPA batch inserts with Spring Data JPA**. why don't you offer a better approach? )

Comment: @Cepr0, It doesn't work with the Spring Data, as it won't allow us to manage transactions manually. A better way will be to use `JdbcTemplate` to manage batch operations.

Comment: @11thdimension What do you say about my attempt (see my answer)? ))

Comment: @Cepr0 It won't work, as processBatch in same class, so Spring can not create a proxy for Transaction.

Comment: @11thdimension Why my test work? )

Comment: If there's no proxy then there's no transaction, meaning if something fails then Spring can not recover.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My approach ))

```
@Service
public class BulkService {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    // @Value("${spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.batch_size}")
    private int batchSize = 20;

    private List<Entity> savedEntities;

    public Collection<Entity> bulkSave(List<Entity> entities) {
        int size = entities.size();
        savedEntities = new ArrayList<>(size);

        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i += batchSize) {
                int toIndex = i + (((i + batchSize) < size) ? batchSize : size - i);
                processBatch(entities.subList(i, toIndex));
                em.flush();
                em.clear();
            }
        } catch (Exception ignored) {
            // or do something...  
        }
        return savedEntities;
    }

    @Transactional
    protected void processBatch(List<Entity> batch) {

        for (Entity t : batch) {
            Entity result;
            if (t.getId() == null) {
                em.persist(t);
                result = t;
            } else {
                result = em.merge(t);
            }
            savedEntities.add(result);
        }
    }
}
```

Working [example](https://github.com/Cepr0/restdemo/tree/master/src/main/java/restsdemo/example18) and [test](https://github.com/Cepr0/restdemo/blob/master/src/test/java/restsdemo/example18/BulkSaveTest.java)